Best practice for suggested edits
On bigger (non-beta) communities, the best practice to suggest an edit includes the rule: "make it substantial" (in fact 2K+ users should have a reject reason titled "No improvement whatsoever").
I'd like to know if the practice it's the same here, or if being the site still in beta and the activity much lower it is tolerated to submit an edit which e.g. just improves the formatting (the question arises from this question, which as of now uses a bulleted list to list a single statement, which IMO would be better formatted using backticks).

I think we haven't discussed about that here but, since the number of suggested edits is really small (432 reviews all-time), it's probably not so important. So, in my opinion, you can submit this kind of edits if you want.

The best practice of all SE sites, including Italian SE, is "the edit should improve the original question/answer." 
When willing to edit, one should ask oneself: Does "wrong" formatting/spelling/grammar/phrasing make the text difficult to understand, or low quality, or not perfectly correct? If it does, then you should edit it, however minor the edit would appear to be. 
But if it does not, then don't touch it to merely satisfy your sense of style or righteousnesses. If the better formatting doesn't particularly address any issues or problems with the question, then there's no point in editing. For example, what would be improved in that question by changing from a single bullet point to another type of highlighting, such as citation or code style? Nothing, wouldn't it?

I agree that's nothing making the question bad, it's not even that I looked for something to improve, for some reason that just sticked out to me: while reading the question the first time I expected the list to go on, but it didn't, and that's why I even noticed; to understand well, do you think that doesn't make up an improvement regardless (i.e. one should avoid performing such edits also if 2K+ user) or do you think that just doesn't make up an improvement good enough to submit an edit into the queue?

@kos, sometimes I edit formatting, or spelling, or grammar, too. Since I'm a moderator (and have 2k+ reputation), I have to think twice before editing anything - because the edit won't go to the queue, there won't be another user, who would check my edits, and all responsibility is mine. If I could suggest an edit, I'd have to be 100% sure that it's a good edit. As a power user, I must be 200% sure that it's worthy, but the principle is the same: Does the edit make the text better? If yes, edit; if not, let it be.
